# Cant't get the mousewheel scroll direction in Firefox with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, mousewheel

I'm trying to get the scroll direction with javascript.
My code works in all browsers except Firefox.
Below is the code for the direction.

```
var wheelDirection = function(evt){
if (!evt) evt = event;
return (evt.detail<0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta>0) ? 1 : -1;
};

var direction = wheelDirection();
```

Below is my complete code where I'm trying do some mouse wheel easing of the scroll using the Greensock js library... It works in all browsers except Firefox where the scroll is constantly down even when scrolling up... Also using feature.js for detection of touch supported device... I just can't figure out what the problem is... Please - no jQuery solutions. I want pure javascript...

```
if (feature.touch) {
  //touch supported
} else {
  //touch not supported    
  function domLoad() {

    scrollTime = 0.6;
    scrollDistance = 360;

    function scroll(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      var wheelDirection = function(evt){
        if (!evt) evt = event;
        return (evt.detail<0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta>0) ? 1 : -1;
      };

      var direction = wheelDirection();
      console.log(direction);
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(direction*scrollDistance);

      TweenMax.to(window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y:finalScroll, easing:Sine.easeOut ,autoKill:true }, overwrite: 10
      });

    }   

    window.addEventListener("wheel", scroll);

  };

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domLoad);

};
```

Comment: `event.deltaY` seems to do the trick now

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth trying, and i have used it in a couple of projects and it appears to work consistanly.

```
var scroll = e.originalEvent.deltaY * -1 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail * -1;
```

Which is running from:

```
.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll")
```

You will then have to check the direction using the scroll var which should be an int.

I found this by console.log out the scroll event value and have a look through the event data, but you will want to check the support when doing so.

Comment: is there a better way these days?

Answer (score 0):

`event.deltaY` of the `wheel` event is a cross-compatible solution for Chrome and Firefox. **Not sure how this behaves with other browsers and devices, however.**